# localization without re-compiling project

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, localization

I am building a project and I need to make it very customizable. I am trying to build it to support 4 languages. And the user will have an admin panel where he/she can change a label's text or a button's text. I want the user to go to that admin panel and change a button's text without calling me :)

I have used old but good style of localization which is .resx files. I have sample code below.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("en-GB"))
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
            label1.Text= FormLabels.test1;
            label2.Text = FormLabels.test2;
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("de-DE"))
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
            label1.Text = FormLabels.test1;
            label2.Text = FormLabels.test2;
        }
     }
```

If I let user to change a button's text in "FormLabels.en-GB.resx" file. the project must be recompiled to see the changes.

I need to find a solution where the user can change the button's text with recompiling. how can I do that?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=satellite+assemblies

Comment: May be it will be helpful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5447/NET-Localization-using-Resource-file

Comment: Could you explain that what does "FormLabels.test1" refers to? I think this part ralated to your code . I want to implement this application to my code. If you explain, I'll glad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think about it to have the localization in external files.
Create a xml file like:

ex: languagesSupported.xml

```
    <Languages>
        <language name="English" file="en.dat" />
        <language name="French" file="fr.dat" />
        <language name="Japanese" file="jp.dat" />
    </Languages>
```

Like this you can actually add more languages later on.

Now in each file you will need to do something like:

(ex: en.dat)

```
    <Language name="English">
        <Localized name="hello" value="Hello">
        <Localized name="goodbye" value="Goodbye">
    </Language>
```

(ex: fr.dat)

```
    <Language name="French">
        <Localized name="hello" value="Bonjour">
        <Localized name="goodbye" value="Au revoir">
    </Language>
```

In your code you would do something like that:

```
    private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> _localizations = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

    private string _currentLocalization = "English";

    private bool LoadLocalizations()
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists("languagesSupported.xml") == false)
            {
                return false;
            }

            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load("languagesSupported.xml");
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("languages/language");

            if (nodeList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                {
                    LoadLocalization(node.Attributes["name"].Value, node.Attributes["file"].Value);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool LoadLocalization(string pLang, string pFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(pFile) == false)
            {
                return false;
            }

            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(pFile);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("language/localized");

            _localizations.Add(pLang, new Dictionary<string,string>());

            if (nodeList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                {
                    _localizations[pLang].Add(node.Attributes["name"].Value, node.Attributes["value"].Value);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void SetLocalization()
    {
        labelHello.text = _localizations[_currentLocalization]["hello"];
        labelGoodbye.text = _localizations[_currentLocalization]["goodbye"];
    }
```

After that, each time your user changes the language, you simply update _currentLocalization and call SetLocalization();

You can even populate your dropdownlist of language using the keys from _localizations.

That way you make the localization completely dynamic.

If you really want to use the CultureInfo, simply map the culture to the language name.

Answer (score 0):

The ResourceManager only works with embeded resources.
You would have to write the ResourceManager yourself.

You could use the ResXResouceSet (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourceset.aspx) and then write your own ResourceManager around it.
It's not that hard to do.
You could then read the resx files and prepend the culture before the resx extension yourself.

Good luck